# how to extract string in R up to the first (and not to the last) occurance of a character?

Tags: r, string

I have a string

"Signal recognition particle subunit SRP72 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SRP72 PE=1 SV=3"

and I would like to extract

"SRP72"

I am trying to use str_extract(), but it extracts pattern up to the last space and not to the first occurrence

```
str_extract(string = "Signal recognition particle subunit SRP72 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SRP72 PE=1 SV=3", 
        pattern = "(GN=).*( )")
```

thus, the pattern I get is "GN=SRP72 PE=1 ". If possible could you please give an answer with str_extract () function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to extract `'GN='` in the final output we can make use lookbehind regex and extract the first word (`\\w+`) after occurrence of `"GN="`.

```
string = "Signal recognition particle subunit SRP72 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SRP72 PE=1 SV=3"
stringr::str_extract(string, pattern = "(?<=GN=)\\w+")
#[1] "SRP72"
```

In base R, we can use `sub` :

```
sub('.*GN=(\\w+).*', '\\1', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regmatches/regexpr` in `base R`

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("(?<=GN=)\\w+", string, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "SRP72"
```

#### data

```
string <- "Signal recognition particle subunit SRP72 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SRP72 PE=1 SV=3"
```